# Able to have interactive login for calls to API Management service?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

We have a backend service that can return a json result (Elasticsearch result) or an interactive browser web page (Kibana) based on the route. This service is gated behind an API Management service. Our developers need to be able to access the web page (Kibana). We are currently using a client certificate and we have it set to require this in our API definition. When browsing to the path in the browser, the user is prompted for the cert and the connection is made.

I would like to get rid of having to manage the certificate and instead use AAD to allow only users in a specific group to be able to access. I understand how to do this when making an API call. Is it possible to also have an experience similar to the cert where if the user is not logged in, they are prompted to log in, and then if they are in the correct group, access would be allowed?

Thanks

Comment: Did you make any progress with your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you want to enforce authentication at APIM level and not in Kibana. For that you'll have to handle two flows:

Initial flow, when non authenticated user requests URL, you should of check for persistent auth, possible in Cookie header and if not found - redirect user to login.microsoft.com.

Returning flow, when Azure AD redirects user back to APIM with a token, you'll need to validate that token and add it to Set-Cookie header, better encrypted.

And finally when any call is made also check and validate the cookie to see if it has expired.

Comment: I can't seem to find an obvious way to do this. I can use a policy to validate a jwt, but that just fails if the req data is not found. How to I redirect to AAD supplying the url to redirect back after the token is obtained?

Comment: you can use on-error policy to catch when validate-jwt fails, see error codes here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-error-handling-policies#predefined-errors-for-built-in-steps. There you could combine choose policy and return-response policy to reply to client with redirect reponse.